# Equal partition for multi-key in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Currently I'm running some Hadoop job using the default partitioner, which generally gives each reducer an equal chunk of data. However, my reducer key consists of two fields:

```
1,foo
2,bar
1,baz
```

and each reducer writes to a different folder depending on the first key.

Suppose I have two reducers, and each of them gets 50% of the data, and write the following files:

```
1/chunk-0     # first reducer
  chunk-1     # second reducer
2/chunk-0     # first reducer
 /chunk-1     # second reducer
```

However, if, say, 20% of first reducer data has key 1 and 80% has key 2, and 50% of second reducer data has key 1 and 50% has key 2, then `chunk-0` and `chunk-1` in each folder are uneven.

How do I ensure that in the final output, the chunks are of equal size in each folder? It seems that I need a partition function that can do something like: for every reducer, n% of that reducer data is key 1, and m% of that reducer data is key 2. Or would it be simpler to do partitioning outside of Hadoop?